# Entity Framework Generic CRUD

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern

I'm about to start a small project using .NET 4, C#, and Entity Framework v4.

I have 50 tables plus. If I write a separate CRUD for each entity (each table) will be a lot of work and I'm practicing DRY. So, I'm thinking of generic CRUD for Entity Framework. But there are pros and cons about generic CRUD.

After searching for a generic CRUD for Entity Framework, I found one at https://github.com/rcravens/GenericRepository
and it has some pros and cons.

```
Cons:

    Hides useful features of the ORM
    Adds complexity to the design

Pros:

    Abstracts away the ORM / persistence implementation
    Allows the persistence layer to be faked for testing
```

So, if you used a generic CRUD of Entity Framework, you had any major problems? Also, are there any generic CRUD for Entity Framework beside [GenericRepository](https://github.com/rcravens/GenericRepository)?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's not 100% to your question because I don't use any generic "CUD" out there but I normaly use the Repository-Pattern. It's rather easy to write a simple abstract-base class that handles most of the EF specifics and you only have to write some case-specific implementations.

see [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175/repository-pattern-tutorial-in-c) for more details on the pattern.

Comment: the answer you refer to is closed, please update your answer.